# QSetting trouble

Tags: c++, qt

I am working with QSettings function. Once successfully set in the .h file variable

```
QSettings *settings;
```

inside the constructor (cpp. file) I set the variable in this way, to obtain a path like Draw/Input/Cells/Width

```
settings = new QSettings("MySoft", "Star Runner");
settings->beginGroup("Draw");
settings->beginGroup("Input");
settings->beginGroup("Cells");
settings->setValue("width", 80);
settings->endGroup();
settings->endGroup();
settings->endGroup();
```

The problem is that width value is properly set to 80 only if during the declaration of the organization name is set to "MySoft": if you assign any other value (e.g. "foobar"), doing a test via

```
qDebug() << settings->value("width", "").toString();
```

the width key as no value

Comment: Does `settings->value("Draw/Input/Cells/width","")` have a value?

Comment: The organization and application name when saving and restoring a value for a key should be the same. You should not expect to get the saved value within another organization name.

Comment: `QSettings` wraps use of registry on windows and ini files on Linux. Providing `organization` and `application` defines where to put registry entries or ini files. So described behavior is expected.

Answer (score 0):

You should also start and end the groups when reading the value. So you could either try

```
qDebug() << settings->value("Draw/Input/Cells/width", "").toString();
```

or

```
settings->beginGroup("Draw");
settings->beginGroup("Input");
settings->beginGroup("Cells");
qDebug() << settings->value("width", "").toString();
settings->endGroup();
settings->endGroup();
settings->endGroup();
```

Comment: Read my question. The is in the organization name

Comment: From your question it is not clear where (in the code) the debug test line is performed. Is that inside the constructor right after you write the value (still inside the nested group)? If not, then please post your complete functions to clarify your question.